# ext4 vs EXFAT: Storage size difference

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, ext4, exfat

I have 2 hard drives, one is EXT4 and one is EXFAT. Both are 8TB, and both contain the same files.

However, if I look at the amount of space being used in Gparted on Ubuntu, there is a big difference. Also included screenshots from the File Manager in Ubuntu.

EXT4: There is 154 GB free.

[image]

[image]

EXFAT: there is 13 GB free.

[image]

[image]

From the screenshots, it looks like both drives have a allocation unit size / block size of 512 bytes, so I don't think (?) that can explain it (could be wrong though).

What gives?

Comment: duplicates: [Same files have different “size on disk” on new drive](https://superuser.com/q/1432383/241386), [Is exFAT less efficient at utilising disk space than HFS+?](https://superuser.com/q/785129/241386), [Please explain wasted space on an exFAT formatted external hard drive](https://superuser.com/a/657410/241386). The reason is simple: the default cluster size on exFAT is huge

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Same files have different "size on disk" on new drive](https://superuser.com/questions/1432383/same-files-have-different-size-on-disk-on-new-drive)

Answer (score 5):

The EXFAT cluster size is not 512 bytes, which explains the difference.

Microsoft's
[Default cluster size for NTFS, FAT, and exFAT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs-fat-and-exfat-9772e6f1-e31a-00d7-e18f-73169155af95)
has this table:

[image]

Your cluster size is then 128 KB, while for ext4 this is likely 4 KB bytes.

Answer (score 1):

By any chance you have mostly large files in thd drives? I had similar questions and I suspect it has something to deal with:

- exFAT uses a File Allocation Table with *pre-allocation*. Meaning files are likely to take up more space than the actual data.
- ext4 on the other hand has delayed allocation [and a lot of other goodies](https://kernelnewbies.org/Ext4#Extents) that will make it more space efficient.
- the fact that [maximum cluster size of exFAT is 32MB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) while extends in ext4 can be [as long as 128MB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4).

To be honest I'm a little surprised how well Ext4 compared with exFAT ^_^